# Typescript export inferred type instead of explicit type

Tags: typescript, vue-router

My context is within `vue-router`, though that's probably not important

I would like to define my routes like this

```
import { RouteLocationRaw } from 'vue-router'

type RouteNames = 'dashboard' | 'flowRun'
type RouteProperties = Record<RouteNames, (...param:string[]) => RouteLocationRaw>

const Route: RouteProperties = {
    dashboard: () => ({ name: 'dashboard' }),
    flowRun: (flowRunId: string) => ({name: 'flow-run', params: {flowRunId}})
} as const
```

however, when I go to use this my types are using the explicit `RouteProperties`, which is actually worse than it would be if I let typescript infer the types. If I import Routes and type `Routes.flowRun`, all I see for params is `...params:string[]` which makes sense since that's how I explicitly defined it.

If I instead define my routes as

```
const Route = {
    dashboard: () => ({ name: 'dashboard' }),
    flowRun: (flowRunId: string) => ({name: 'flow-run', params: {flowRunId}})
} as const
```

now when I import Routes, and use `Routes.flowRun`, my parameter is named with an explicit type and will not let me call without providing the param.

Is it possible to have the type safety of my explicit types when defining new routes, but still export as the inferred types for a better type safety when used?

Comment: Is there a reason to not define the types in reverse, e.g. `const Route = {...}; type RouteNames = keyof typeof Route; type RouteProperties = typeof Route;`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by using an identity function. The generic constraint will enforce that the input value extends the constraint, but will return the actual type of the input value:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgJQIYHcAyEDGqbAQB2cAvnAGZQQhwDkAbgK4CmAtNUzC1HQNwAoGAE8wLFBC4tseAsTTo4AXhQYZ+QkUECcxAM7xO3AHKoQLPcrgBtOgBNUegBYAjCKih26AGnoUANhDoyExEdAC6cI5wukQGgiJiElKm5laJLBAUcEYsqRbWREwgLjzhCaLiyJLcAArUYrDAFlbILLqeADzVKWYsvgAUAHQjYB5mAFwGUMBEAObW4QCUygB8ydzqckQKq9oUoTjbcBkAyqgULD11DZadACpwLAAe3ER2ltcs9RCNBBarAazMBcCZwe5LMEIARwGwAaTgszgAGsWMIsuCopYES83h8UWiMV8fn9mpYAPxwBFgogsBhlMH3axw8ICcjQ2GxAxwGog+AqBAjIbArikQSwijQOADLnwVHCREkXlcFYc2GI7IDACEA1y+Us0VCyKIQRI0WmswWy2FRBw-iYdgsA3lS1VMPVsMd-hY3B5XD51nl5XdsNI7rDsKgPqYUCV-q4gjDOn08C+6Uq50uxNuAzVDmcbg8djBAxWSnWubgRD6YPsjlc7k8dDIS287oCQRCRBLHeCoQAksW4Bb5mWKwhq+Za72OKEfHAxlAzHoob2u4PSKRW+7uAYwQBGABMAGY21vtFyIN6hoE5gMAPIuABW7RgQ3legGX1dfDgAHo-xsOsC0bLxfDoNc53CIA)

```ts
import { RawLocation } from 'vue-router';
type RouteLocationRaw = RawLocation;

const routeNames = ['dashboard', 'flowRun'] as const;
type RouteName = typeof routeNames[number];
type RouteProperties = Record<RouteName, (...param:string[]) => RouteLocationRaw>;

function typeSafeRouteProps <T extends RouteProperties>(input: T): {
  [K in keyof T as K extends keyof RouteProperties ? K : never]: T[K]
} {
  const output = {...input};
  for (const key in output) {
    if (!(routeNames as unknown as string[]).includes(key)) {
      delete output[key];
    }
  }
  return output;
}

const Route = typeSafeRouteProps({
  dashboard: () => ({ name: 'dashboard' }),
  flowRun: (flowRunId: string) => ({name: 'flow-run', params: {flowRunId}}),
  test: 123,
});

console.log(Object.keys(Route)); // ['dashboard', 'flowRun']
```

Comment: FYI: I'm not sure how to explicitly request an npm package version in the TS playground, but I discovered that you're using a beta version (`4.x`) of `vue-router`, (which is why I've aliased the `RouteLocationRaw` type in my answer: it doesn't exist in the current stable (`3.x`) release).

Comment: Thanks @jsejcksn, but it seems the `Route` const has lost the type safety when defining new routes. I was able to add `test: 123` to the object with no errors

Comment: @stackoverfloweth You might think of that as undesirable, but TypeScript is [structurally-typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html), so that's permissible by the compiler. I'm curious: what would be the issue in your case?

Comment: well if you look at my first code snippet, that enforces that each Record<> value is a function that returns a valid route. So it is possible to have type safety when adding new routes, and it's definitely possible to export them as unique methods. I want to find a way to accomplish both

Comment: @stackoverfloweth In that case, you can add a runtime transformation of the input object to delete all unknown keys from the object. There's still a caveat here that the keys need to be enumerable, but as long as you're passing in an object literal, that would never be a problem. I've updated my answer to reflect this idea.

Comment: sorry, I do not want to support having `test:123` in the Routes. I want Routes to enforce that every property be a function that returns a valid route

Comment: Take a closer look. The entry `test: 123` gets deleted from the return value: it's not in the `Route` object.

Comment: @stackoverfloweth Did you look again? The function requires any values on the enumerated keys to be the correct type, and it deletes any keys which aren't in the enumeration.

Comment: yes, it's neat to see what's possible but ultimately doesn't fulfill what I'm looking for. I want an error on screen if another developer tries to define a route that is not a function that returns `RouteLocationRaw`

Comment: @stackoverfloweth I understand. Unfortunately, it's not possible to keep the types as written and also enforce that they conform to another shape without a bit of runtime code: precisely because of structural typing.