# Typescript type function without specifying params

Tags: typescript, vue-router

I'm looking to define a type that loosely defines a function by return type

I could write my type as

```
type FunctType = (...param:string[]) => RouteLocationRaw
```

Which would allow for zero+ string params and enforce that the function return `RouteLocationRaw`.

Ideally though, I would accept any function with any params, as long as it returns `RouteLocationRaw`.

Is this possible?

Comment: you can use `any` type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by using `any[]` as the rest parameter type:

```ts
type Acceptable = (...args: any[]) => RouteLocationRaw;
```

---

Inferring `RouteLocationRaw` from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70428565/438273):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbxgTzAUzgJQIYHcAyEAxtjMBAHZzYDOWEArjGoSWZTrgL5wBmUEEHADkANwZoAtAKZoowgNwAoJSnRwAYhQA8SuHAAK2KNhB00AD2YUAJnQYUA1hQi4KAbQC6cALzUKyF4ANHpYaDQMADbwftgBIQB8vnAAFAB0GWDGpjQAXIbZZgCUvkmY4VEwyqqoGACCRERoYDDYAEaRGH5a2nGBnkH0sqyk5BScCdU2aESRxhhElDTwkcT5mIzMI+zjeNWLFMt8FACM+Q1NLe2dySklPkmrRMoHR7wUAEznjc2tHV2pMBnODLKDACgAc3uj2ILyW8HeAGZvpc-jc-CkgflQeCIYMwF84BQGCA2nJoXAnnDDgiKAAWFG-a4Au6lOB0j4KOAAem5cDkAigSletIArIyrv9bhT3MIABZoSKrYSeLm8-lQQVKIA)

```ts
import {type RawLocation as RouteLocationRaw} from 'vue-router';

type Fn<
  Params extends unknown[] = any[],
  Result = any,
> = (...params: Params) => Result;

type Acceptable = Fn<any[], RouteLocationRaw>;

declare const loc: RouteLocationRaw;

const fn1: Acceptable = () => loc;
const fn2: Acceptable = (p1: string) => loc;
const fn3: Acceptable = (p1: string, p2: number) => loc;
const fn4: Acceptable = () => 42; // error
const fn5: Acceptable = () => ['hello']; // error
```